# Test failing ndb transaction

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions, app-engine-ndb

I would like to unittest what happens if a transaction in ndb fails when calling a put function from a model.
Is it possible to make a transaction fail on purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions):

> If the function raises an exception, the transaction is immediately aborted and NDB re-raises the exception so that the calling code sees it. You can force a transaction to fail silently by raising the ndb.Rollback exception (the function call returns None in this case). There is no mechanism to force a retry.

You can raise an exception in your unittest instead of your put() routine to simulate that event, and it should emulate the same outcome - because a failure to put will cause the all datastore events in the transaction to rollback anyway.

You might find [these kinds](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions) of transaction exceptions:

> You can receive Timeout, TransactionFailedError, or InternalError exceptions in cases where transactions have been committed and eventually will be applied successfully.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the Timeout, TransactionFailedError, and InternalError exceptions. My client caches an object being saved in transaction if the transaction succeeds. I catch exceptions and return an error to the user in the event of failure, but do those exceptions mean it may or may not actually later complete the transaction. How should I report this scenario to a client? The docs for Timeout for example say that it may or may not have failed. Does this mean you can essentially never be sure what to tell a user what happened in the event of an exception?

Comment: @RichardBender For most transactions, you'll want them to retry a number of times (I believe the default is 3). *make sure they are idempotent*

The error you'll want to provide, for all of these, is usually a "temporary site error" message, because they all refer to a piece of the AppEngine service being unavailable. (Transient Errors).

As for the validity of an object, you should always attempt to retry a timeout error, because you can never be sure. Imo, this would involve ONLY showing success when you are certain of it (i.e. never in the case of timeout)